# Dart when using JQuery plugin for slider doesn't work as JavaScript did

Tags: javascript, jquery, dart, flexslider

I'm beginning at using Dart for my Front-End development but I'm having some troubles. What I need is to use a JQuery plugin called FlexSlider http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ through the Js-Interop Dart Library. However it isn't working as it did with pure JavaScript and I can't even understand the bunch of illegible code that generates Dart2Js.

The code is this:
Edit 1: I fixed it removing the document.ready and adding de js folder when importing js.dart.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main()
{
    js.scoped(()
    {
        var element = js.context.jQuery('.flexslider');
        var options = js.map
        ({
            'animation' : 'slide'
        });
        element.flexslider(options);
    });
}
```

Of course I have the js.dart library file in the 'packages' folder inside the folder where my dart script is. And of course I have previously loaded JQuery in the HTML document where I'm calling the JavaScript generated by Dart2Js.

After correcting with the Alexandre's feedback...
Such as it's right now Google Chrome Inspector is throwing the following 2 errors:

1
**Uncaught ReferenceError: ReceivePortSync is not defined / (1):24**
The StackTrace:
 - ProxiedObjectTable / (1):24
 - (anonymous function) / (1):162
 - (anonymous function) / (1):511
 - $.$defineNativeClass.nY indexz.dart.js:1986
 - $.fb indexz.dart.js:1087
 - bind indexz.dart.js:1089
 - $$.e7.P indexz.dart.js:612
 - $$.J1.P indexz.dart.js:454
 - $.Zs indexz.dart.js:1215
 - $.i indexz.dart.js:1217
 - $.e indexz.dart.js:1220
 - $.s indexz.dart.js:1219
 - $.E2 indexz.dart.js:1117
 - $$.aX.vV indexz.dart.js:767
 - $.Rq indexz.dart.js:1190
 - (anonymous function) indexz.dart.js:2830

2
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get$g' of null indexz.dart.js:439**
The StackTrace:
 - $$.J1.get$g indexz.dart.js:439
 - $.sL indexz.dart.js:1293
 - $.fC indexz.dart.js:1205
 - $.$defineNativeClass.JX indexz.dart.js:1907
 - $.i indexz.dart.js:1217
 - $.e indexz.dart.js:1220
 - $.s indexz.dart.js:1219
 - $.E2 indexz.dart.js:1117
 - $$.aX.vV indexz.dart.js:767
 - $.Rq indexz.dart.js:1190
 - (anonymous function) indexz.dart.js:2830

My HTML code in HEAD is this:

```
<pre>
<head>
    <?php script('jquery') ?>
    <?php script('flexslider') ?>
        <script>
            jQuery = $.noConflict();
        </script>
    <?php script('indexz.dart') ?>
    <?php wp_head() ?>
<?php woo_head() ?>
    <?php style('global') ?>
    <?php style('flexslider') ?>
</head>
</pre>
```

My HTML code for the Slider is this:

```
<pre>
<div class="flexslider col-full" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <?php image('1.png') ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php image('2.png') ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php image('3.png') ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php image('4.png') ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</pre>
```

I clear that I'm working with Wordpress and PHP and the image, script and style PHP functions work perfectly generating the corresponding HTML tags for each element and file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/) your import should be `import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;`.

You can also skip `js.context.$(document).ready` because Dart `main()` does the same.

Because of a [Dart2js bug](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2265), you have to alias `$` with `jQuery = $.noConflict();` to make the javascript compiled code working.

Finally, a working example could be :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  js.scoped(() {
    var element = js.context.jQuery('.flexslider');
    var options = js.map({
      'animation' : 'slide'
    });
    element.flexslider(options);
  });
}
```

with

```html
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js'></script>
<script>
  var jQuery = $.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="application/dart" src="my_script.dart"></script>
<script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"‌​></script>
```

Comment: Alexandre. Please, review my edit. I fixed all as you told me. I'm still having errors. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget `<script src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>` in your html page.

Comment: Even if I am compiling it to pure JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. `ReceivePortSync` is defined in `dart.js` and must be loaded to make *js-interop* work.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. Now I'm having troubles because my Wordpress Template calls a plugin extension named fitDivs for responsiveness when it's mobile-sized. :/

Comment: Now it works perfectly. It seems it's not necesary to call the $.noConflict() method anymore.